# odoo 14 Unhandled Promise done is not a function

Tags: javascript, python, odoo, odoo-11, odoo-14

I am facing a problem `this.get_critical_paths(events).done is not a function`

When I tried debugging the problem I can see the
`console.log(paths)`

Then I got this

**`Unhandled Promise Rejection: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: paths`**

I am not sure what to do to fix the problem.
This is the code that should return the `paths` var

```
@api.model

def calc_critical_paths(self, project_ids):

    res = {}

    projects = self.env['project.project'].browse(project_ids)

    for project in projects:

        res.update({

            project.id: self.calc_critical_path(project)

        })

    return res
```

I am trying to upgrade [The project timeline critical path](https://github.com/OCA/project/tree/11.0/project_timeline_critical_path)

```
            if (this.modelName === 'project.task') {
                this.get_critical_paths(events).done(function(paths) {
                    this.critical_paths = paths;
                    this.draw_canvas();
                }.bind(this));
            }
```

### Kindly give suggestions to improve the question instead to dismissing it

Answer (score 1):

I tried installing the the module and dependence the error was
related to the `.done` so i change it `.then` and it started working try it

### change

```
if (this.modelName === 'project.task') {
               
                this.get_critical_paths(events).done(function(paths) {
                    this.critical_paths = paths;
                    this.draw_canvas();
                }.bind(this));

            }
```

### to

```
if (this.modelName === 'project.task') {
               
                this.get_critical_paths(events).then(function(paths) {
                    this.critical_paths = paths;
                    this.draw_canvas();
                }.bind(this));

            }
```

not sure what will be the over all effect and new in odoo and js

Comment: It worked, sow then in other odoo js but did not know the difference. thank you for the help